# Express JS app on Heroku shows Application Error

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I am trying to host my Express JS app on Heroku, I have uploaded it on my gitHub repo and associated it with my heroku account. I created the Procfile with content

```
web: node app.js
```

But when I go to my application link on Heroku it gives Application Error.

What I am doing wrong? Do I need to give my index.js instead of app.js?

Comment: run `heroku logs`, there should be some clues in there

Comment: When I view Heroku logs on my terminal it says “Your version of git is 1.9.3. Which has serious security vulnerabilities”. But I doubt this has anything to do with my app not being able to run on Heroku.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded my git to 2.3.0 and now the logs are coming in. It seems the issue was that no web dynos were running.

I went in my terminal and did

heroku ps:scale web=1 --app myappname

and now the application is working

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my git to 2.3.0 and now the logs are coming in. It seems the issue was that no web dynos were running.

I went in my terminal and did

heroku logs --app myappname

heroku ps:scale web=1 --app myappname

and now the application is working